# Tags added to WordPress are not saved

Tags: wordpress, post, tags

Why when I add tags in WordPress is it always blank when I publish or draft?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: check your console. it may be issue with script error

Comment: make sure you use this structure and wait for your tags to show up under that input box -> `tag1, tag2, tag3`